# SDL not printing to console

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm trying to use SDL with Visual Studio 2019 but my programs are only showing an empty console. At the moment I just want to be able to compile my program with the SDL libraries.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "yee haw!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code is just giving me a console with the text:

(process 32) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .

Where I would want 'yee haw!' preceding it.
It works fine when I take out the `#include <SDL.h>` (but I want the SDL.h)

I've heard that SDL now redirects to a stdout.txt file but I couldn't find that anywhere. I've also tried displaying a window with code from a tutorial I found, but that also gives me the empty console.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows and SDL 2.0.9

Thanks!

Comment: SDL 1.2 used to redirect stdout/stderr on some platforms; SDL2 does not. You can redirect it yourself though. The problem is not really related to SDL, windows differs "console" and "GUI" programs, and for GUI programs you don't see their output (but it is there). You can open command prompt, navigate to your program's directory, and do something like `your_program.exe > stdout.txt` to redirect output to file just to make sure you actually have output there.

Answer (score 1):

By default, SDL uses a macro hack to replace the `main` function. The user defined `main` function must be in the following format:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // whatever
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want this behaviour you can use `SDL_SetMainReady`.

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL.h>

int main()
{
    SDL_SetMainReady();

    // whatever

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @LordPotato Perhaps your SDL library has been compiled with STDIO redirection. Is it creating `stdout.txt` in the executable directory?

Comment: Don't know what STDIO redirection is, but there is no .txt file, only a .ilk and .pdb

Comment: @LordPotato There's a macro you can set when compiling SDL that causes all console output to be redirected to txt files. Unfortunately if that's not it then I'm out of ideas, sorry.